# add anchor tag on triggered event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have been struggling to add the `<a></a>` on `mouseup` or `click` event in the html document.

My requirement is to add anchor tag on the clicked part the moment user clicks in the html page.

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt && tgt.nodeName === 'SPAN') {
    alert(e.target.id);
    tgt.classList.add('strong');
    var randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    alert('#'+randomString);
    var attrHref = '#'+randomString;
    tgt.id.add(randomString);
    tgt.href.add(attrHref);
    var newNode = document.createElement('div');
    //g.setAttribute('id', randomString);
    //alert( e.currentTarget === this );
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = attrHref;
    alert(a.href);
    //a.setAttribute('href', '#'+randomString);
    //g.appendChild(a);
    alert("afterAppendChild");
    tgt.href = attrHref;
    tgt.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", a);
    document.activeElement.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", a);
    alert("after insertA");
    alert('done');      
  }
});
```

In the html I do not have specific ids in the DOM elements which I can fetch so I am trying to add the `<a></a>` tag where user clicks. I am able to make the text bold but not able to add `<a></a>`

Kindly guide me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution on this. Below is the source code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).click(function(e){
  var randStr = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
  var attrHref = '#'+randStr;

    var div = $('<div id='+randStr+' class="a-wrapper">')
      .css({
        "left": e.pageX + 'px',
        "top": e.pageY + 'px'
      })
      .append($('<a id='+randStr+' href='+attrHref+'>Link'+randStr+'  </a>'))
      .appendTo(document.body);
      var blob = new Blob([$("html").html()], {type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"});
      saveAs(blob, 'page.html');
    });    
</script>

<style>
body {
  position: relative;
}

.a-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like many tags, the  attribute, has an `onclick` event (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

You wish to add "onclick" event to all of the A, then start with:
`document.getElementsByTagName("a")`

it will return an array of all the  on your page. 
then add the listener:
`addEventListener('click'.. )`

so you will have something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a").addEventListener('click',(event) => {
//    YOUR FUNCTION HERE 
// if the user should not be moved to the href add:
// return false
// or use event.preventDefault()
})
```

Comment: I do not want to `getElementByTagName` since the requirement is to add `a` tag. I need to add the anchor tag where the user clicks. Also I cant even get the element by `id ` as there is possibility that where user clicks the wont be available.